# Difference between two roots using bisection method in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, bisection

I have written this C code to compare the root of two functions using bisection method. My first function (g(x)) executes correctly but the second one (h(x)) outputs "#1QO" on screen. I can't find what I did wrong in the code.

Can you please explain?
Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef double (*DFD) (double);

double g (double x) 
{
   double y;
   y = pow (x,3) - pow (x,2)-1;
   return y;
}

double h (double x)
{
  double k;
  k = 1.0 + (1.0/x) + (1.0 /pow (x,2));
  return k;
}

double bisection (DFD f, double x0, double x1,double tol)
{
   int i;
   double middle;
     for (i=1;i<=50;) {
     middle = (x0+x1)/2.0;
     if (fabs (middle - x0) <tol) return middle;
     if (f(middle)* f(x0) <0.0) x1 = middle;
     else x0 = middle;
     }
 }

 int main () {
 double root_gx, root_hx = 0.0;

 root_gx = bisection (g,0,2,0.0005);
 printf ("Root found using g(x) = %.3lf\n",root_gx);

 root_hx = bisection (h,1,2,0.0005);
 printf ("Root found using h(x) = %.3lf\n",root_hx);

 printf ("Difference between the two roots = %.3lf\n", (fabs (root_gx- root_hx)));

return 0;

}
```

**EDIT**: *Initialised i=1 in bisection and changed `bisection (h,0,2,0.0005)` to `bisection (h,1,2,0.0005)` and it works* Thanks everyone!

Comment: Minor: Why `50`?  Maybe `DBL_MANT_DIG` instead?

Comment: `int i; ... for (;i<=50;) {` is a problem as `i` is not initialized.

Comment: i have changed i=1 and bisection `(h,1,2,0.0005)` and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Value not initialized leading to undefined behavior. Set to some value.

```
// int i;
int i = 0;
...
for (;i<=50;) {
```

---

`i` is never incremented.
`50`  is arbitrary.

Recommend using the binary precision of `double` as `bisection()` halves each iteration.

```
for (i=0; i <= DBL_MANT_DIG; i++) {
  ...
}
return middle;
```

---

Also recommend an algorithm change to allow a change of |difference| of 0.0 to meet a tolerance of 0.0.

```
// if (fabs (middle - x0) <tol) return middle;
if (fabs (middle - x0) <= tol) return middle;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double h (double x)
{
  double k;
  k = 1.0 + (1.0/x) + (1.0 /pow (x,2));
  return k;
}
```

gives division by zero if `x==0.0`. You do this when you call `bisection (h,0,2,0.0005);`, which calls `f(x0)`, which is `h(0.0);` in this case.

If you divide through an input parameter in a function, then you should always check, if the actual value of the input parameter is not equal to `0.0`:

```
double h (double x)
{
  if ( x == 0.0 ) return 1e99; // infinite
  double k;
  k = 1.0 + (1.0/x) + (1.0 /pow (x,2));
  return k;
}
```

Comment: I tried changing 0 to 1, `bisection (h,1,2,0.0005)`,  but still it's giving the same error.

Comment: @A.DeMartini Perhaps `middle` becomes 0.0.

Comment: See [`int i;` comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374709/difference-between-two-roots-using-bisection-method-in-c#comment56493344_34374709)

Comment: `bisection()` does no division by 0.0 in OP's original code nor this answer.  Re-writing it does not help.  Division by 0 is a problem of `f()`, not `bisection()`.

Comment: Why is that potential division by zero even a problem? And returning 0 instead is even less safe.